How to sign Pdf using iTextSharp 4.1.6 and certificate marked non-exportable, located in Windows Certificate Store
I have been able to sign a document with a certificate that was installed on the machine with "export key" option enabled. But when I try the same thing with a non-exportable certificate, it fails to load the private key.
I am aware that X509Certificate2.PrivateKey is depricated and x509Certificate2.GetRSAPrivateKey() function should be used instead, but I don't know how because Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair() throws an error if used with GetRSAPrivateKey().
This is the verison of the code that works, only when certificate is installed as exportable:
            X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

            using (X509Store localMachineStore = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
            {
                localMachineStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                X509Certificate2Collection wantedCertificateCollection = localMachineStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, @"123456798", true);
                if(wantedCertificateCollection.Count != 1)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Certificate not found in Store!");
                }

                certificate = wantedCertificateCollection[0];
            }

            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(reportBytes);

            using (MemoryStream fout = new MemoryStream())
            {

                try
                {
                    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, fout, '\0');

                    PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
                    signatureAppearance.Render = PdfSignatureAppearance.SignatureRender.NameAndDescription;
                    signatureAppearance.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
                    signatureAppearance.Acro6Layers = true;
                    signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(380, 230, 550, 280), pdfReader.NumberOfPages, "CustomField");

                    AsymmetricAlgorithm privateKeyAsymAlgo = certificate.PrivateKey; // <--- THIS LINE THROWS EXCEPTION IF CERTIFICATE IS MADE NON-EXPORTABLE

                    Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(privateKeyAsymAlgo).Private;

                    Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate chain = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certificate);
                    
                    
                    signatureAppearance.SetCrypto(asymmetricKeyParameter, new[] { chain }, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);

                    stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
                    stamper.Close();

                    return fout.ToArray();

                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }

I am aware that I'm using outdated library. We are in the process of migrating the code base, but as it is a legacy system it takes time and in the meantime it needs to work as is.
Application is using .Net Framework 4.6.2
